# Unable to mount a volume on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I attached a volume to an EC2 instance and now when i'm trying to mount it i'm getting this error :

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/tmp
mount: /mnt/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

I was using a Amazon Linux 2 image so i have to mount the volume using this command

```
sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/xvdf1 /mnt/tempvol
```

And now it works.

Comment: This worked for me! as I was having duplicate UUID while trying to attach Secondary Storage

Comment: This happened to us when we created a new EBS volume from an existing snapshot and tried to mount it

Comment: This was so helpful, and I've never seen the '-o nouuid' mentioned in any of the AWS documentation.  Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create filesystem on this volume:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
```

And then you can mount it.

**Please remember, that it will format this volume**

Answer (score -1):

Please check for the mount partition name (/dev/xvdf), the name should be `/dev/xvdf1` like this if the disk is partitioned or you can try with below command:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol -t ext4
```